# RegEx Capturing indefinitely repeating patterns with specific backreferences?

Tags: regex, textwrangler, find-replace

I'm trying to find a good regex to use with TextWrangler to parse task descriptions into a Rememberthemilk.com format: so that a line like:

```
Example task section 1 section tomorrow section tagone tagtwo tagthree tagfour
```

whould convert into the RTM format:

```
Example task !1 ^tomorrow #tagone #tagtwo #tagthree #tagfour
```

Now this gets me into the question of, how do you capture an infdefinitely-repeating pattern using the right syntax in the backreferences?

I've been trying this regex:

```
^([\w ]+) section (\d) section (\w+) section ((\w+) )+$
```

which seems to capture the format of the input text, but I just don't know how to make the conversion in the backreferences?

```
\1 !\2 ^\3 #(???)
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Each character in the replacement string gets used exactly once.  There's no way to repeat the "#" for each match of the final group.  If there were always the same number of tags, you could match them individually, but I'm assuming that's not the case.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this just with replacement and backreferences. Doing this in a more fully-fledged programming language might let you do it (e.g. C# has the ability to access all captures for a particular group). Example: https://gist.github.com/Porges/9ba3b7f94f2c14e20feb16c984406e5a#file-example-cs

Answer (score 0):

Capture quantified constructs, don't quantify capture groups.

here we also use "grouping only" parens (no capture group) on the inner section and capture the outer to get a clean result:

```
([\w ]+) section (\d) section (\w+) section ((?:\w+\s?)+)
```

you want the repeated constuct *inside* the capturing `()`, it doesn't make sense to "repeat the group", in most engines only the last result the group matched will be captured. (though some regex engines will allow a repeated capture group to remember all sub-matches (.NET for example))

demo: https://regex101.com/r/y3CryR/2